# how to ignore hotkeys in os x

Tags: cocoa, macos, events, macos-carbon, hotkeys

do the Mac OS X APIs provide a method to ignore all systemwide hotkeys? I'm currently researching how to build a kiosk-mode like application. I searched the OS X Developer documentation and tried google (combinations of [cocoa, carbon, os x, ignore, global, hotkey, kiosk, event]), but nothing turned up yet.

I know this has been done before (Camino KioskMode Plugin for instance) - but it seems to me as if those who succeeded kept the solution to themselves. I'm currently lost - if someone could give me a hint I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks for your time.

Till Backhaus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Snow Leopard or later:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you need to support earlier versions:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2062/